# Сubes for photo.HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="portfolio__body">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried to do it with `flex` but it didn't work.
I want the cubes to be like in the picture

---

[image: I want the cubes to be like in the picture]

Comment: please share also your css for the snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, using `flexbox` as specified. The trick here is to use `flex-wrap` so the squares do not overflow your container. Have in mind to adjust the `max-width` of `portfolio__body`  according to your need. Hope this helps.

```css
.portfolio__body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 300px;
  align-items: center;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio__body">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.portfolio__body {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     list-style: none;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     gap: 1rem;
}
 .square {
     background: #f00;
     flex: 1 1 calc((100% / 2) - 2rem);
     color: #fff f;
}
 .square::before {
     content: '';
     float: left;
     padding-top: 56%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="portfolio__body">
  <li class="square">1</li>
  <li class="square">2</li>
  <li class="square">3</li>
  <li class="square">4</li>
  <li class="square">5</li>
  <li class="square">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not good answers. Also this doesn't resemble what OP wants

Comment: Edited. Please check now . I think he edited post or image was not loaded for me.